# Equivalent Java code for BXML

Tags: java, apache-pivot

I'm trying to understand how *Apache Pivot* builds a GUI from it's definition in a *BXML* file. I want to make sure that I understand which steps are involved and what is done automatically during these steps. For this, I tried translating a BXML definition for a very simple GUI to pure Java. But it seems that layouting is not done the same way (or at all) when following the steps that are described in the [BXML Primer](http://pivot.apache.org/tutorials/bxml-primer.html).

This is the BXML file and the accompanying class to load the file:

*example.bxml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Frame xmlns="org.apache.pivot.wtk">
    <TextArea text="Hello World" />
</Frame>
```

*WithBxml.java*:

```
public final class WithBxml extends Application.Adapter {
    @Override
    public void startup(Display display, Map<String, String> properties) throws Exception {
        Frame frame = (Frame) new BXMLSerializer().readObject(WithBxml.class, "example.bxml");

        frame.open(display);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DesktopApplicationContext.main(WithBxml.class, args);
    }
}
```

This creates the following GUI, which is expected:

[image]

I'm trying to use the following code to recreate the same GUI. But the `TextArea` is not visible, as can be seen in the following screenshot.

*WithoutBxml.java*:

```
public final class WithoutBxml extends Application.Adapter {
    @Override
    public void startup(Display display, Map<String, String> properties) throws Exception {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setText("Hello World");

        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.add(textArea);
        frame.open(display);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DesktopApplicationContext.main(WithoutBxml.class, args);
    }
}
```

[image]

What do I need to change in the class `WithoutBxml` to get the same result as with the BXML file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking `frame.add(textArea);`, I had to use `frame.setContent(textArea);` to add the `TextArea` to the `Frame`. This method is called when loading the BXML file because the `Window` class is annotated with `@DefaultProperty("content")`:

```
@DefaultProperty("content")
public class Window extends Container {
    ...
}
```

Because of this, `BXMLSerializer` is calling `setContent()` for child elements of the `<Window>` element in the BXML file.